# Unable to run WebDriver in firefox

Tags: eclipse, selenium

I am running Selenium-Webdriver. I have installed Jre, Eclipse JUNO, and added firefox driver. 
I have run the first program from this source.

http://www.guru99.com/first-webdriver-script.html

The error I get is:

Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:

Firefox starts but cannot go to the url.

OS: Win 7
I have unpacked eclipse in D drive. 
workspace is C:\Users\Home\workspace.
Home is "Standard User"

Comment: If you are using Windows 7 or higher, it is possible that you blocked the Java runtime using UAC.   That is what it sounds like to me.

Comment: I have executed program using Standard User. To test i had changed privilege to Administrator->restart Pc->run program. I get the same result.

Comment: Are you using that exact code or have you modified it in any way?

Comment: I have used exact code. Code complies correctly, throws a runtime error. Only change is that eclipse JUNO is used instead of eclipse Indigo. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the selenium driver and firefox are up to date, this issue can be caused with incompatibilities between the web driver and firefox

Comment: I have updated both. Selenium driver version is 2.40.0. Firefox is also updated(27.0.1)

Comment: Downgrade your FF version to 26; this is a possible duplicate. Somehow it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to Firefox version 22 and try it

Answer (score 0):

I have done more analysis of the problem.

I changed the program to run with IE. I changed first few lines-

```
File file = new File("D:\\Android\\IEDriverServer\\IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath() );  
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

while running this program Windows firewall will block the execution. It will ask weather to allow or not. By selecting allow i can run the program. So i have to allow Firefox driver so that it is not blocked by Windows firewall.

by selected settings in contol panel we can change setting of a program. following link is helpfull

http://www.technipages.com/blockunblock-programs-in-windows-firewall

In my PC "Command line server for the IE driver is allowed access. For firefox driver i am not sure which program should be allowed access. I have added eclipse.exe to list but that does not solve issue. Please help.